# Why Would React Change Image File Extension On Build

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using create react app and have an image tag that was inadvertently capitalized (tony.JPG).  I did a build and successfully pushed the app to production on Heroku.  However, I realized the capitalization issue and change the extension to its proper lower case (tony.jpg). However, the build file still showed with the capitalized extension.  I deleted the build file and did a new build but got the same issue again.  I resolved the issue by changing the img tag src but I have a lingering question.  Why would react keep capitalizing the image extension even though the image file was changed to lower case and there was a new build?

I am using Node, Express, & Create React App.  I've tried changed the file path in explorer directly and in my client > public > images > tony.JPG.  It may be related but the build > images folder not only has the capitalized extension but has two other files (one that is tony.JPG~e5463541ef50286886de13e03dea670ef69c85c6 and another file called tony.JPG~HEAD).

Images name in public folder (tony.jpg):
[image]

Image in build folder (tony.JPG):
[image]

Comment: What OS are you using? The type of filesystem could make a difference here.

Comment: Windows.  I have had an issue in Visual studio in the past where a capitalization from a rename made in VS did not change the file name, but in this case I changed it in both VS and in the explorer folder.

Answer (score 0):

As @Matt-holland mentioned the type of OS matters, OSX is type insensitive if you're using it

If you run `git mv tony.JPG tony.jpg` it will rename it in git

Comment: I am using Windows 10.  I believe the issue is a bug as the issue resolved itself (i.e. the file name changed) after I ended up doing a hard reset on the PC.  It could be an issue with my machine and/or VS.  Hopefully this will help someone else that comes across the same issue.

Comment: Not sure what the right thing to do in this situation is but maybe leave an answer yourself and mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was resolved when I did a hard reset on my PC.  I am using Windows 10. I believe the issue is a bug as the issue resolved itself (i.e. the file name changed) after I ended up doing a hard reset on the PC. It could be an issue with my machine and/or VS. Hopefully this will help someone else that comes across the same issue.